# Matching keynum to an array index number?

Tags: javascript, loops, button, for-loop

I have an array , with the index numbers set from 65 -90 (a-z keycodes).
I want to loop through my array to see if the keynum produced from a keypress event matches one of the index numbers, and if it does, turn the colour of an onscreen button red, and write the String.fromCharCode to the innerHTML of an element.

Lets say my button is this...

```
<input type="button" id="a" value="A">
```

This is my JS code...

```
document.onkeypress = keypress;


function keypress() {
    var a = document.getElementById("a");
    var b = document.getElementById("b");
    var c = document.getElementById("c");
    var d = document.getElementById("d");
    var e = document.getElementById("e");
    var f = document.getElementById("f");
    var g = document.getElementById("g");
    var h = document.getElementById("h");
    var i = document.getElementById("i");
    var j = document.getElementById("j");
    var k = document.getElementById("k");
    var l = document.getElementById("l");
    var m = document.getElementById("m");
    var n = document.getElementById("n");
    var o = document.getElementById("o");
    var p = document.getElementById("p");
    var q = document.getElementById("q");
    var r = document.getElementById("r");
    var s = document.getElementById("s");
    var t = document.getElementById("t");
    var u = document.getElementById("u");
    var v = document.getElementById("v");
    var w = document.getElementById("w");
    var x = document.getElementById("x");
    var y = document.getElementById("y");
    var z = document.getElementById("z");

    var buttons = [];
    buttons[65] = a;
    buttons[66] = b;
    buttons[67] = c;
    buttons[68] = d;
    buttons[69] = e;
    buttons[70] = f;
    buttons[71] = g;
    buttons[72] = h;
    buttons[73] = i;
    buttons[74] = j;
    buttons[75] = k;
    buttons[76] = l;
    buttons[77] = m;
    buttons[78] = n;
    buttons[79] = o;
    buttons[80] = p;
    buttons[81] = q;
    buttons[82] = r;
    buttons[83] = s;
    buttons[84] = t;
    buttons[85] = u;
    buttons[86] = v;
    buttons[87] = w;
    buttons[88] = x;
    buttons[89] = y;
    buttons[90] = z;

    var keynum = (window.event) ? event.keyCode: e.which; 
    var panel = document.getElementById("panel");
    var letter = String.fromCharCode(keynum);
    for(i = 65; i <= buttons.length; i++)
    {
        if(buttons[i] == keynum)
            {
           buttons[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
                panel.innerHTML += letter;


            }
    }
}
```

How can I make it so that when I press a button, the corresponding onscreen button turns red? 
This is my JS Fiddle ...
http://jsfiddle.net/AdamMartin121/VXYFC/14/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function keypress() {


    var buttons = [];
    for (var i = 65; i <= 90; i++) {
        buttons[i] = buttons[i + 32] = document.getElementById(String.fromCharCode(i + 32));
    }

    var keynum = (window.event) ? event.keyCode : e.which;
    if (buttons[keynum]) {
        buttons[keynum].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    }
}
```

You were comparing `buttons[i]` with `keynum`. But `buttons[i]` contains a document element, not a number. You just want to use `keynum` as the index into the `buttons` array.

I changed the `buttons` array to have entries for both upper and lowercase letters, and used a loop to fill it in. You only had entries for uppercase, so you had to press Shift to make anything happen.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/VXYFC/16/)

Comment: Thankyou very much, sir! That makes a lot of sense, I have to start writing things down before I delve in there. Very helpful!